# How to determine if Latitude is North or South, or Longitude West or East with Geolocator?

Tags: c#, geolocation, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm building an Universal App in WinRT and am able to get the Latitude Longitude of my device using the Geolocator. But for my input I also need the direction (North, South for Latitude and East West for Longitude).

But how do I know if a Latitude or Longitude is within a specific direction? Is there a build-in way, or what would be the calculation to do this?

*51.3705* to **51.3705N**

*6.1724* to **6.1724E**

```
Geoposition GeoPosition = await GeoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
double Latitude = GeoPosition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
double Longitude = GeoPosition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
```

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common sense :):

```
private string ConvertLatitudeToGPS(double Latitude)
    {
        string Direction = "";
        double UnformattedLatitude = Latitude;
        if (Latitude > 0)
        {
            Direction = "N";
        }
        else
        {
            UnformattedLatitude = UnformattedLatitude * -1;
            Direction = "S";
        }
        string GPSString = UnformattedLatitude.ToString("0.0000") + Direction;
        return GPSString;
    }

    private string ConvertLongitudeToGPS(double Longitude)
    {
        string Direction = "";
        double UnformattedLongitude = Longitude;
        if (Longitude > 0)
        {
            Direction = "E";
        }
        else
        {
            UnformattedLongitude = UnformattedLongitude * -1;
            Direction = "W";
        }
        string GPSString = UnformattedLongitude.ToString("0.0000") + Direction;
        return GPSString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.basicgeoposition.aspx).

Instead of adding S/N or W/E to indicate the direction, you will get values from -90° (S) to 90° (N) and -180° (W) to 180° (E). The docs doesn't explicitly specify which direction is positive, but what I've written here should be the most common convention.